# Duplicate Points

Tags: postgresql

How to find duplicate points(poi) in an area by creating a radius for each points and Return all results within a specific radius?

[image]

Comment: Please **edit** the question to show what you have tried so far.  It might help to explain *why* you want this, in case your intended solution isn't the best one.

Comment: Why within a radius. If the point is a duplicate, the radius is irrelevant, is it not?

Comment: Even after you edit, it still isn't clear how the radius in any way relates to duplicates. You can find duplicates with ST_Equals (and other ways), but if a point is the same as another, the radius is totally irrelevant.

Comment: hi john,
thanks for your comment.
it is not like that, i want find the points which lies in same geom,then compared with another geom and the name of the point is also compared

Comment: In the above picture,you can see four 'A' points, i have to find first comparison for the duplicates which is in radius,(Two A Points).

Comment: Ah, so duplicate by label, not by geometry?

Comment: Do you wish to eliminate the duplicates, or just report them?

Comment: You still need to **edit** the question to include enough information about the table name and geometry column name, and your initial attempt at a self-join query

Comment: Have you tried ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints(geom) ?http://postgis.net/docs/ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints.html

Comment: john,
ya i want to report them,also by label and by geometry i want to report the duplicates.

Comment: @elmo, I think that is repeated points within a geometry, not repeated points with different attributes.

Comment: @MohamedAshrafAliB I think that it's important to share your SQL querie to understand what you want do ans brin you some solution

Comment: As a new user please take the [Tour].  In the comments here and on the answer to your question it has been suggested several times that you **edit** your question to provide additional information.  For recommendations on how questions can be structured to attract potential answerers I suggest reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353

Answer (score 1):

One approach, is to use a spatial self join, so you compare all points with all others (you set a.id != b.id, to avoid comparing a point with itself), then use ST_DWithin for a radius search (replace 10 with you own number).

```
SELECT count(b.label), a.label, a.geom 
FROM points A, points B
WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 10)
AND a.id != b.id   
GROUP BY a.id, a.label, a.geom;
```

If you only want to return those points that have a duplicate label (or whatever your attribute is called), then add

```
HAVING count(b.label) > 1
```

at the end.

If you wish to see which ids (whatever you primary key is called) share a common label, you can use array_agg like this:

```
SELECT count(b.label), a.label, array_agg(b.id), a.geom 
FROM points A, points B
WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 10)
AND a.id != b.id  and a.label = b.label  
GROUP BY a.id, a.label, a.geom;
```

Comment: thanks john,
i tried, but it doesnt meet my output,somewhat yours is right.ok john,just go through the query which i used,in that i cant able to retrive geom and id
select a.name,Count(a.name) from poi a WHERE GeometryType(ST_Centroid(the_geom)) = 'POINT' AND ST_Distance_Sphere( ST_Point(ST_X(ST_Centroid(the_geom)), ST_Y(ST_Centroid(the_geom))), (ST_MakePoint(72.89894,19.07710))) <= 1 * 20 GROUP BY a.name HAVING ( COUNT(a.name) > 1 );

Comment: @MohamedAshrafAliB can you edit your first question by adding the last querie? because we cant read the querie

Comment: select a.name,Count(a.name) from poi a WHERE GeometryType(ST_Centroid(the_geom)) = 'POINT' AND ST_Distance_Sphere( ST_Point(ST_X(ST_Centroid(the_geom)), ST_Y(ST_Centroid(the_geom))), (ST_MakePoint(72.89894,19.07710))) <= 1 * 20 GROUP BY a.name HAVING ( COUNT(a.name) > 1 );